autECLConnList.Count returns 0
I am writing some VBA code to read values from an excel file, put those values into an AS400 window and then scrape some values off that AS400 window.  I am using VBA 6.0, and IBM Iseries Access for Windows (PCOMM) v13.0.
My code, so far, is as follows:
Dim PSObj As Object
Dim autECLConnList As Object
Dim num As Long
Dim autECLPS As Object
Dim textValue As String

'BringSessionToFront

Set autECLConnList = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnList")
Set PSObj = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLPS")

' Initialize the session
autECLConnList.Refresh

num = autECLConnList.Count

MsgBox num

The same code was working sometime back. After restarting the machine, I could nt do anything with code and it is not working , Please help me here
For the problem, It is not establishing the connection between PcOMM and VBA. I have already add the all references in VBA
